# Javascript Multiplayer Game - Server Side Validation.

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm starting my hand at creating a multi-player game using HTML 5 / Javascript.

I'm currently doing some prototypes on different ideas on how to stop people from cheating. Now I know I need to do everything server side and just have the client sending "actions".

My issue is I can't workout the best way to store the game state for each player.

So just looking at something basic; Two players running round a empty map.

Currently my idea is

Both clients(sockets.io) send their actions to a Node.JS server that then responds with a X/Y coord. This is fine. But obviously both clients need to know where the other player is.

I thought about doing this by creating a new database table for each game and having the game state stored in there so the two node.js connections can talk to eachother.

My question is, is this the best way to interact between two node.js connections, would it be fast enough? Or is there a design patten for this specific task that I'm missing?

thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, no system should dynamically create *tables* in a database, create records within a table, fine, but actual physical tables - no.

Comment: I did originally think this. But my I thought it might be more optimized to have a lots of tables with very few records?

Comment: @Jamiec that sounds like wisdom but I'm not convinced. Why would that be a general rule? Are tables really more _physical_ than records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new table per game is generally considered a Terrible Idea.

If you don't need persistence -- ie. in the case your Node.js server croaks, a game may be lost -- you can simply store the games in memory, in an object, let's say `games`, which might contain an object that has an array of `players`, each of which might contain `x` and `y` coordinates, etc.

```
var games = {
  123019240: {
    players: {
      123: {x: 1, y: 1, name: 'Joe'},
      456: {x: 2, y: 2, name: 'Jimbob'}
    }
  }
};
```

If you do need persistence, though, you really should probably look into some other databases than SQL -- for instance [Redis](http://redis.io) *might* be a good choice for the task.

In any case, SQL feels like the wrong tool, and creating new tables on demand even more so. (If you are using SQL, though, consider a table layout with `game_id`, `player_id`, `x` and `y` and be sure to have an index on `game_id` :) )

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was originally thinking doing what you are saying above. But I cant see how the two connections would be able to read each others player data? 

e.g. Joe is connected via a browser to a node.js server.
     Jimbob is also connected via a browser to the same server. 

But wont node.js create two instances that cannot talk to eachother? and therefore cannot read object data between eachother without storing it somewhere first?

Comment: No, it's all in the same process (unless you specifically tell it not to, via the `cluster` module). Any and all global variables will be accessible to both (or rather, all) clients.

Comment: And let it be added that you could also have a second Node.js (or other language) process that is your (in-memory, if you like) database, if you can't be sure your game will remain uni-process.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you need to take is the following:

Each client sends it's coordinate to the server at specific intervals (using `emit`). The server checks this position for validity and stores it the db. It then uses a broadcast message (http://socket.io/#how-to-use - Broadcasting messages) to send this position to all the clients.
Each client in turn will update the displayed position of the character/player that moved.

You cannot create a direct connection between two players because they are using a browser. Each connection must pass through a single node.js server.

You can view some tutorials here:
http://www.nodejs-news.com/nodejs-tech/Nodejs-Socketio-Building-HTML5-game/

(They use the Impact engine but the principles are the same)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if you have users interacting with each other in a clustered server environment, its best to have them interacting on the same server.

Example:

5 game servers, people create games together in a lobby. A game contains a max number of people. With this scenario, it is much much much easier to keep the *game* on one server, and make all users connect to that one game server. This prevents needed convo between servers, and keeps game state consistent and fast!

Eve Online is a great example of this. Each 'region' is it's own server, and when you travel far enough through the universe, you are transparently moved to another game server. That way if you're fighting somebody, chances are they're on the same server. Then the game server is free to periodically write data to the DB. This is the best way, as the user never has to wait for the DB. They communicate directly with the game server, game server communicates with DB every once in a while. At most, your user would lose only a few seconds of data (and so would everyone else on that game server).